# Analytical expression of the minimizer of cross entropy loss when the predicted function is a constant fucntion?

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, cross-entropy

Let $\{y_1...y_n\} \in \{0,1\}$, and let $c \in [0,1]$. Define the cross-entropy of loss of $c$ by:

$$C(c): = \sum_{j=1}^{n}- y_j  ln c - (1- y_j) ln (1-c) $$.

Define $c*= arg min _{c} C(c)$

Is there an analytical expression of this $c*$, in terms of $\{y_1...y_n\}$? I'm asking this question motivated by other two loss functions: $L^1, L^2$ loss, i.e. quadratic and absolute losses for $c$, where the median and the mean of $\{y_1...y_n\}$ are the corresponding minimizers of $C(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively interested in the Maximum Likelihood Estimate of a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p=c$.

Taking the derivative in $c$ gives $-\sum_{j=1}^n y_j/c +(1-y_j)/(1-c) = 0.$

Define $Y_n:= \sum_{j=1}^n y_j$. Then

$$-\frac{1}{c}Y_n+(n-Y_n)\frac{1}{1-c}=0,$$

giving:

$$c=\frac{Y_n}{n}.$$

Taking a step back, this should be obvious, as the numerator counts the number of successes $(y_i=1)$ and the denominator counts the number of trials.